# Translation Management Workflow Side-by-Side comparison with English

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-foundation, workflow, language, comparison

I'm trying to evaluate whether SharePoint and specifically the Translation Management Library will be acceptable for our workflow. I have some questions:

1. Is there a way to show say an English document side-by-side with a translated document while maintaining sync to each topic header and/or section?
2. I watched a demo on SP2010 where it showed that updating a link or topic in one document required manually updating it in all the other language documents. Is this still required in SP2013? Or has this been improved?
3. When assigning a specific translator, can they be to an external email for say contractors?

Thanks.

Comment: interesting question - did you find a solution/answer in the meantime? could you please post it here?

Comment: Unfortunately, no solutions/answers were discovered.